# How to get rdlc report on my C# project

Tags: c#, rdlc

I can not get the rdlc report on my C# project ,on debug exe .....can any one help me to get it.......If i install the visual stdio, then i get the rdlc on my exe , but with out it..... rdlc ont show on my exe..........i want just to show on my project with out install the visual stdio

Comment: have you installed/deployed somewhere and want get over there?

Answer (score 1):

For these so called "local reports", you need to do one of two things:

1. When installing your application on the client machine, also install the RDLC file and reference the installed RDLC file in the respective properties of the Report Viewer Control. Keep in mind that the installation location on the user's machine may be different from your development folder, so you must make sure the path to the RDLC file is not hardcoded.
2. Embed the RDLC file in the application's resources and have the Report Viewer Control reference the RDLC resource

Of course, if you don't ship the RDLC file, the report can not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the `ReportPath` of your `rdlc` file, you can specify the `ReportEmbeddedResource` which is somehow similar to specifying a path that is contained in your project. E.g., if your application is called `TestApp` and the `rdlc` file is in the `Resources` folder, you can just set

```
myReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "TestApp.Resources.MyReportFile.rdlc";
```

However, this must happen in the code before the release, of course.